# Extra single quotes in azure loadbalancer

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I am trying to get a helm chart deployed with the following command:

```
helm upgrade nifi  ./nifi -n nifi \
  --set service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"=\"true\" \
  --dry-run | grep "load-balancer"
```

But it returns back

```
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: '"true"'
```

How do I go about getting it so that it is without the single quotes?

```
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to escape the `"`.

The command should be:

```
helm upgrade nifi  ./nifi -n nifi \
  --set service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"="true" \
  --dry-run | grep "load-balancer"
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I get the following error:

Error: UPGRADE FAILED: unable to decode : json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go struct field ObjectMeta.metadata.annotations of type string

Comment: are you using zsh ? or bash ? or something different?

Comment: I'm usinng bash.